# Meteor Installation - standard-minifier-css taking 2+ hours to install

Tags: meteor

I'm using Windows Powershell to create a meteor app. I have ran the command:

```
meteor create simple-todos
```

and for the past hour it has been saying:

```
Loading package standard-minifier-css...
```

I'm new to meteor, but all I've done up to this point is follow the installation instructions on their website and executed the command above. How long should this process take, and why is it taking so long?

Meteor Version: 1.11.1

Operating System: Windows 10

Comment: There are three important questions that you need to answer when it comes to unexpected behavior during installing packages or running the Meteor tool: Which Meteor release do you use (`meteor --version`) which operating system is this and are you behind a proxy? Based on that people can start investigating.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I will update my question with that info! I don't think I'm behind a proxy, but not sure how I would find this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not normal for it to take so long and it's probably related to your Windows permissions. I would try checking if you used Chocolatey to install Meteor, they do list a couple of requirements to correctly run Powershell to give it the right Administrative rights. This includes running the resulting Powershell as an Admin.

Then on Meteor's site it does say that you should disable all anti-virus software, including Microsoft's defender as it probably tries to check on each file you are trying to install through Powershell. If that doesn't work, check in the Issues section in Meteor's github, you can usually search to find people with similar issues or create your own to get some free professional help on Windows specific issues.

I would recommend just getting a simple open-source Virtual Machine app and making a Ubuntu installation. Things are a bit more sorted on the Linux side of things, just because of the nature of file permissions - obviously you would need some basic Linux knowledge to get things going correctly there, but usually you would deploy a Meteor app using cheap cloud servers running Ubuntu, so you might want to get ahead of it.

Comment: Turning off Windows Defender while I installed has done the trick! Thanks so much!

Comment: Yep, disabling the antivirus was it. I excluded the folder in which the meteor project was located in the security check so that I didn't have to disable the antivirus, I followed [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security-811816c0-4dfd-af4a-47e4-c301afe13b26) in order to do that